# php echo within an echo for a checkbox

Tags: php, html, input, checkbox, echo

I'm trying to use checkboxes to display and update records in a MySQL database. I want to change the value of the checkbox based on whether it's checked or unchecked. But I'm getting this error:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING

Here's the line of code that's throwing the error:

`echo"<input type='checkbox' name='PLJan' {if (isset($_POST['PLJan'])) print 'value='checked''} $row->PLJan /> January ";`

Is there a better way for me to do this so that saving it will update the database with 'checked' if the box is checked, and a blank if the box is unchecked?

Thanks in advance for the halps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
echo"<input type='checkbox' name='PLJan' {if (isset($_POST['PLJan'])) print 'value='checked''} $row->PLJan /> January ";
```

should be

```
echo"<input type='checkbox' name='PLJan'"; 
if (isset($_POST['PLJan'])) { echo " value='checked'"; } 
echo $row->PLJan . "/> January ";
```

Comment: Thanks! I had to take the `{`s out, but it works great. Only for some reason, it's submitting "on" as the value instead of "checked". I don't think the word "on" is anywhere in the file.

Answer (score 1):

Your notation is all off ... simplest solution is to break it apart to muliple echo statements.

```
echo "<input type='checkbox' name='PLJan' ";
if (isset($_POST['PLJan'])){  
        echo  "checked='checked'";
} 
echo "value='".$row->PLJan."'/> January ";
```

With that you can simplify it using a ternary if

```
echo "<input type='checkbox' name='PLJan' ";
echo (isset($_POST['PLJan'])?"checked='checked'":"");
echo "value='".$row->PLJan."'/> January ";
```

And if you want to compress it down to a single line you can concatenate the echos together

```
echo "<input type='checkbox' name='PLJan' ".(isset($_POST['PLJan'])?"checked='checked'":"")." value='".$row->PLJan."'/> January ";
```

Comment: Good answer, can you guess what $row->PLJan will spit in the middle of html tag

Comment: @Neeraj I'm going to assume that is his value... updated answer to reflect that and changed the previous value attribute to a checked attribute

Comment: I changed it to 
`echo"<input type='checkbox' name='PLJan'"; 
  if (isset($_POST['PLJan'])) echo 'value="checked"'; 
  echo $row->PLJan . "/> January ";` And it works. It's just submitting "on" to the database instead of "checked".

Answer (score 0):

You can't include PHP logic in the moddle of a string. You'll need to break it up:

```
echo"<input type='checkbox' name='PLJan'";
if (isset($_POST['PLJan'])) echo ' checked';
echo " {$row->PLJan} /> January ";
```

Comment: This answer itself is not formatted properly, the first line needs a `"` at the end to be in proper syntax

Answer (score 0):

```
?>
<input type='checkbox' name='PLJan' <?php if (isset($_POST['PLJan'])) echo 'checked="checked"'; ?> /> January
<?php
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
<?php

echo"<input type='checkbox' name='PLJan'";

if (isset($_POST['PLJan']))
{
 echo ' checked';
}
echo " {$row->PLJan} /> January ";
?>
```